# How do you predict an outcome using a single value in a multiple logistic regression using statsmodels?

Tags: linear-regression, logistic-regression, statsmodels, predict

```
#import the needed pandas module  
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

#Upload the contents of an excel file to a DataFrame
df= pd.read_excel("C:/Users/ME/OneDrive/Desktop/weather.xlsx")

#Create a multiple logistic regression model
logRegModel = smf.logit('sunny ~ temp + barom', data = df)

#Fit the data in df into the model
results = logRegModel.fit()

#Print the results summary
print(results.summary())



#plot the scatterplot with the actual data
z = df.sunny
x = df.temp
y = df.barom

#make a prediction for a given temp x and barometer y reading 
prediction = results.predict(pd.DataFrame({'temp': [21],'barom':[12]})
prediction.summary_frame(alpha=0.05) 


# Creating figure
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")

# Creating plot
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "blue")
plt.title("3D scatter plot")

# show plot
plt.show()
```

I ran the code above. Everything works fine until it hits the code for making a prediction using a single x and a single y value. When I run the code to include:

```
#make a prediction for a given temp x and barometer y reading 
prediction = results.predict(pd.DataFrame({'temp': [21],'barom':[12]})
prediction.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)
```

I recieve the following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-78-b26a4bf65d01>", line 36
    from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is so incredibly odd??? WHy does it run perfectly  without the two prediction lines above and then when I include them it tells me a simple import function is a syntax error? It is my understanding reading the statsmodels docs, that in order to make a prediction for a multiple logistic regression model I need to pass a dataFrame into the predict function. Wasn't this done correctly above? My logistic regression is trying to predict if there is a sunny day from temperature and barameter reading. WHen I comment out the import statement above and run it I receive another error on another import statement. This is so strange. WHy soes it not accept my import statements? I ran the code on multiple IDEs and receive the same results. Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: Hi Jack  The code in the question has an unclosed parenthesis on line 25. It should say: `results.predict(pd.DataFrame({'temp': [21],'barom':[12]}))`

Comment: In Python 3.10+ you should get a better error message saying: `SyntaxError: '(' was never closed`

Comment: Awesome Alexander ! That did it !  Much obliged. I wonder if there is any function to print out the stats of the prediction. I know that there is a  prediction.summary_frame(alpha=0.05) 
But I get errors when I use it for " predict"

Comment: I receive two values when I run the code. I was expecting one value. Is there any reason why I am receiving two values as such : 0 and .99998                                                   
        "The predicted probability of winning is 0    0.998165"

Comment: `predict` method only returns the predicted value. The `get_prediction` method returns additional information like standard error of the predicted value and confidence interval.